# addEventListener to button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, dom-events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

In this code I'm into a function that fills each table row with data from a JSON file. I added a button near each row of the table. When I click each button I want it to perform a function (even just a simple alert at the moment). This is my code:

```
function fillRow(employee){

var data = "";
var buttonCars = document.createElement("button");
var showCars = buttonCars.innerHTML = "show cars";

buttonCars.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('example alert');
});
        data =   "<tr>" + 
"<td>" + employee.name + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + employee.surname + "</td>" +
"<td>" + employee.email + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + "<button>" + showCars + "</button>" 
 + "</td>" + "</tr>";

return data;

}
```

Right now, nothing happens when I click the button and I don't understand why?

Comment: You are doing `document.createElement("button")`, and also manually writing `"<button>" + showCars + "</button>"`. You are therefore creating two buttons, one programatically and one in the template. You are attaching the click handler to the one created programmatically, which lives only in memory, and was not added to the DOM. You are clicking the template button, which has no `click` listener, so, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an event handler to `buttonCars`, but not putting `buttonCars` in the page anywhere; it doesn't survive the return of the function. Your function just returns a string of HTML (without that button), so it can't hook up an event handler via `addEventListener` (and the way it can, `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, is generally poor practice).

Instead, have your function return an actual `tr` element with its rows and the button:

```
function fillRow(employee){
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = `
        <td>${employee.name}</td>
        <td>${employee.surname}</td>
        <td>${employee.email}</td>
        <td><button>show cars</button></td>`;
    tr.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("example alert");
    });
    return tr;
}
```

Note that this changes how you use the return value from `fillRow`, because it returns an actual element, not a string. So you'd append it to a `tbody` element (typically) rather than treating it as HTML.

Here's an example creating a short table:

```js
function fillRow(employee){
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = `
        <td>${employee.name}</td>
        <td>${employee.surname}</td>
        <td>${employee.email}</td>
        <td><button type="button">show cars</button></td>`;
    tr.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("example alert");
    });
    return tr;
}

const employees = [
    {name: "Joe", surname: "Bloggs", email: "joe@example.com"},
    {name: "Muhammad", surname: "Abu-Yasein", email: "muhammad@example.com"},
    {name: "María", surname: "Gutierrez", email: "maría@example.com"},
];

const tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

// Add the already-known employees
// (Generally best when doing lots of appends to use a document fragment
// or, in modern environments, the new `append` method that lets you
// provide multiple elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append),
// to avoid multiple distinct DOM modifications.)
tbody.append(...employees.map(fillRow));
/* Here's what it looks like with a fragment
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (const employee of employees) {
    frag.appendChild(fillRow(employee));
}
tbody.appendChild(frag); // Appends the fragment's children, not the fragment
*/

// Allow adding new ones
document.getElementById("btn-add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const name = document.getElementById("new-name").value;
    const surname = document.getElementById("new-surname").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("new-email").value;
    const employee = {
        name, surname, email
    };
    employees.push(employee);
    tbody.appendChild(fillRow(employee));
});
```

```css
label {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<div>
    <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" id="new-name">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Surname:
        <input type="text" id="new-surname">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Email:
        <input type="text" id="new-email">
    </label>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="btn-add">
```

(That uses a lot of `id`s for the form, which I don't normally, but it's quick and easy for the example.)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest two approaches that do not mix HTML and JavaScript code?

#### Approach 1: *ad hoc* code

A relatively simple approach where the functions are tightly bound to the specific table you want to populate

```js
function addCell(data) {
  const tdElem = document.createElement('td');
  if (data instanceof HTMLElement) {
    tdElem.append(data);
  } else {
    tdElem.innerText = data
  }
  return tdElem;
}

function handleCarBtnClick(employeeId) {
  window.alert(`${employeeId}'s car`)
}

function fillEmployeeRow(employeeData) {
  const trElem = document.createElement('tr');
  const btnCarElem = document.createElement('button');
  btnCarElem.innerText = 'show cars';
  btnCarElem.addEventListener('click', () => handleCarBtnClick(employeeData.name));

  trElem.append(addCell(employeeData.name));
  trElem.append(addCell(employeeData.surname));
  trElem.append(addCell(employeeData.email));
  trElem.append(addCell(btnCarElem));

  document.querySelector('#employees-table').append(trElem);
}

// Populating the employees table

[{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    email: 'john.doe@email.tld'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    surname: 'Doe',
    email: 'jane.doe@email.tld'
  },
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    surname: 'Bar',
    email: 'foo.bar@email.tld'
  }
].forEach(employee => fillEmployeeRow(employee))
```

```html
<table id='employees-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Approach 2: reusable generic functions

I admit this is probably an overkill for such a simple case but, just for fun and for the sake of promoting good (?) practices...

```js
// Reusable functions

function addCell(data) {
  const tdElem = document.createElement('td');
  if (data instanceof HTMLElement) {
    tdElem.append(data);
  } else {
    tdElem.innerText = data
  }
  return tdElem;
}

function addRow(data, fields, targetTable) {
  const trElem = document.createElement('tr');
  fields.forEach(field => trElem.append(addCell(data[field])));
  targetTable.append(trElem);
}

function addButton(btnText, btnClickHandler) {
  const btnElem = document.createElement('button');
  btnElem.innerText = btnText;
  btnElem.addEventListener('click', btnClickHandler);
  return btnElem;
}

// Populating the two tables using the same functions

// Employees table

function handleCarBtnClick(employeeId) {
  window.alert(`${employeeId}'s car`)
}

[{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    email: 'john.doe@email.tld',
    salary: 30000
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    surname: 'Doe',
    email: 'jane.doe@email.tld',
    salary: 30000
  },
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    surname: 'Bar',
    email: 'foo.bar@email.tld',
    salary: 30000
  }
].forEach(employee => {
  const args = {
    data: {
      ...employee,
      btn: addButton('show cars', () => handleCarBtnClick(employee.name))
    },
    fields: ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'btn'],
    targetTable: document.querySelector('#employees-table')
  };

  addRow(args.data, args.fields, args.targetTable)
});

// Departments table
[{
    name: 'Sales',
    location: '2nd floor, Building A',
    phone: '123456789'
  },
  {
    name: 'Marketing',
    location: '2nd floor, Building A',
    phone: '123456789'
  },
  {
    name: 'Human Resources',
    location: '1st floor, Building A',
    phone: '123456789'
  }
].forEach(department => {
  addRow(department, ['name', 'location'], document.querySelector('#departments-table'));
});
```

```html
<table id='employees-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table id='departments-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```